# Modifying a JS browser extension's HTML parser to exclude images

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I'll get out of the way that although I have a programming background I have no experience with any of the tools or languages I'm working with here. Sorry if I've made simple misunderstandings or communicate something unclearly.

I'm using an extension to generate EPUBs from website links. The extension has the option to customize the parsing logic from the options dialog. Doing so yields this code for the parser it's currently using:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var dom = parser.parseFromString(source, "text/html");

var new_link = null;
var subchaps = [];

// Wordpress content
var main_cont = dom.querySelector(".entry-content")
if(main_cont != null){
  var ancs = main_cont.querySelectorAll("a");
  ancs.forEach((element) => {
        if(RegExp(/click here to read|read here|continue reading/i).test(element.innerText)){
          new_link = helpers["link_fixer"](element.href, url);
        } else if (RegExp(/chapter|part/i).test(element.innerText)) {
          subchaps.push(helpers["link_fixer"](element.href, url))
        }
  });
}
if (new_link != null) {
    var res = await fetch(new_link);
    var r_txt = await res.text();
    dom = parser.parseFromString(r_txt, "text/html");
    var out = helpers["readability"](dom);
    return {title: out.title, html: out.content};
} else if (subchaps.length > 0) {
    var html = "";
    for(var subc in subchaps){
      console.log(subchaps[subc]);
      var cres = await fetch(subchaps[subc]);
      var c_txt = await cres.text();
      var cdom = parser.parseFromString(c_txt, "text/html");
      var out = helpers["readability"](cdom);
      html += "<h1>"+out.title+"</h1>"+ out.content
    }
    return {title: title, html: html};
}
var out = helpers["readability"](dom);
return {title: out.title, html: out.content};
```

I've inspected this code and gathered that it handles three cases: two ways that it needs to follow links deeper before parsing, and the simple case where it is already in the right place. The lions share of the code deals with the first two cases and it's largely the third that I'm interested in. Unfortunately, it appears that the second to last line is where the parsing actually happens:

```
var out = helpers["readability"](dom);
```

And this is a magic box to me.  I can't for the life of me figure out what this is referencing.

I've searched the full file for a definition of 'helpers' or even 'readability' but come up blank. I was under the impression that the part I was editing *was* the 'readibility' parser. I thought I'd be able to pop into the parser logic, add a line to exclude nodes with the `<img>` tag, and live happily ever after. What am I mistaken about? Or is what I want to do impossible, given what the extension is letting me modify?

To be clear, I am not asking for a full guide on how to write parser logic. I considered just parsing and repackaging the document before the line in question, but I didn't want to write the same code 3 times, and I don't like that I can't tell what it's doing. I couldn't even begin to search for documentation, given that I can't find the definition in the first place. Even just explaining what that line does and pointing to any relevant documentation would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

(And here is the full file, if you feel like verifying that I didn't miss anything.)

```
main_parser: |
  var link = new URL(url);
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var dom = parser.parseFromString(source, "text/html");
  switch (link.hostname) {
    case "www.novelupdates.com":
      var paths = link.pathname.split("/");
      if (paths.length > 1 && paths[1] == "series") {
        return {page_type:"toc", parser:"chaps_nu"};
      }
  }
  // Default to all links
  return {page_type:"toc", parser:"chaps_all_links"};
toc_parsers:
  chaps_nu:
    name: Novel Update
    code: |
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var dom = parser.parseFromString(source, "text/html");
      var chap_popup = dom.querySelector("#my_popupreading");
      if (chap_popup == null) {
          return []
      }
      var chap_lis = chap_popup.querySelectorAll("a");
      var chaps = [];
      chap_lis.forEach((element) => {
          if (element.href.includes("extnu")) {
              chaps.unshift({
                  url_title: element.innerText,
                  url: helpers["link_fixer"](element.href, url),
              });
          }
      });
      var tit = dom.querySelector(".seriestitlenu").innerText;
      var desc = dom.querySelector("#editdescription").innerHTML;
      var auth = dom.querySelector("#authtag").innerText;
      var img = dom.querySelector(".serieseditimg > img");
      if (img == null){
        img = dom.querySelector(".seriesimg > img");
      }
      return {"chaps":chaps,
       meta:{title:tit, description: desc, author: auth, cover: img.src, publisher: "Novel Update"}
      };
  chaps_name_search:
    name: Chapter Links
    code: |
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var dom = parser.parseFromString(source, "text/html");
      var ancs = dom.querySelectorAll("a");
      var chaps = []
      ancs.forEach((element) => {
            if(RegExp(/chap|part/i).test(element.innerText)){
              chaps.push({
                  url_title: element.innerText,
                  url: helpers["link_fixer"](element.href, url),
              });
            }
      });
      return {"chaps":chaps,
        meta:{}
      };
  chaps_all_links:
    name: All Links
    code: |
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var dom = parser.parseFromString(source, "text/html");
      var ancs = dom.querySelectorAll("a");
      var chaps = []
      ancs.forEach((element) => {
          chaps.push({
              url_title: element.innerText,
              url: helpers["link_fixer"](element.href, url),
          });
      });
      return {"chaps":chaps,
        meta:{}
      };
chap_main_parser: |
  var url = new URL(url);
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var dom = parser.parseFromString(source, "text/html");

  // Generic parser
  return {chap_type: "chap", parser:"chaps_readability"};
chap_parsers:
  chaps_readability:
    name: Readability
    code: |
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var dom = parser.parseFromString(source, "text/html");

      var new_link = null;
      var subchaps = [];

      // Wordpress content
      var main_cont = dom.querySelector(".entry-content")
      if(main_cont != null){
        var ancs = main_cont.querySelectorAll("a");
        ancs.forEach((element) => {
              if(RegExp(/click here to read|read here|continue reading/i).test(element.innerText)){
                new_link = helpers["link_fixer"](element.href, url);
              } else if (RegExp(/chapter|part/i).test(element.innerText)) {
                subchaps.push(helpers["link_fixer"](element.href, url))
              }
        });
      }
      if (new_link != null) {
          var res = await fetch(new_link);
          var r_txt = await res.text();
          dom = parser.parseFromString(r_txt, "text/html");
          var out = helpers["readability"](dom);
          return {title: out.title, html: out.content};
      } else if (subchaps.length > 0) {
          var html = "";
          for(var subc in subchaps){
            console.log(subchaps[subc]);
            var cres = await fetch(subchaps[subc]);
            var c_txt = await cres.text();
            var cdom = parser.parseFromString(c_txt, "text/html");
            var out = helpers["readability"](cdom);
            html += "<h1>"+out.title+"</h1>"+ out.content
          }
          return {title: title, html: html};
      }
      var out = helpers["readability"](dom);
      return {title: out.title, html: out.content};
  chaps_raw:
    name: No Parse
    code: |
      return {title: title, html: source}
```

Comment: This `helpers["readability"]` is https://github.com/mozilla/readability They define these methods in https://github.com/maoserr/epublifier/blob/master/src/entry/sandbox.ts If what you want is to ignore the `<img>` tags, then you could modify the yaml you've got so that these tags are removed before the get to that Readability module. I suppose `dom.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(img => img.remove())` should do it (in some places it's `cdom` instead of `dom`).

Comment: I suspected I might need to dig through the extension itself, not just the parts it showed me in the options dialog. It certainly wasn't my intention to make you do that for me, but I'm very grateful you did. It looks like this will work for me just fine. Again, thanks a bunch for your help.